# Clicking button on webpage using VBA

Tags: vba, web

I wish to click a button using vba.

The source code of the webpage is below:

`<input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Check sort code" class="ajax-processed"> </pre>`

I have tried `ie.document.getelementbyID("edit-submit").click` but it is not working.

I have tried preceding it by `ie.document.getelementbyID("edit-submit").fireevent ("onclick")` but this is also not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it part of a form, you'd need to submit the form.

Comment: Thanks Nathan - I have tried ```ie.document.form(0).submit``` but this brings up the another webpage which is not the right one.

Comment: Can you show the page or the html?

Comment: https://www.chequeandcredit.co.uk/information-hub/sort-code-checker-tool

Comment: I tried ```ie.document.getElementById("search-block-form").submit``` but the incorrect webpage is loaded.

Comment: Sorry it's ukpa-sort-code-checker-form this form, but still having issues, i'll keep trying

Comment: @Nathan_Sav any joy?

Comment: No, i've been snowed under at work myself.

Comment: @nathan_sav ok any ideas on who might be able to help?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav any news?